# Вывод переменной в шаблон Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

Помогите чайнику в Ларе. Не могу понять почему не выводится переменная в шаблоне, вот контроллер:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    protected $category;

    public function __construct()
    {
      $this->category = Category::all();
    }
    public function category_page($id) {
        $category = $this->category->find($id);
        $title = $category->title;

        return view('header', ['title' => $title]);
    }
}
```

Шаблон header:

```
    <a href="" class="top__menu-item">{{$title}}</a>
```

Ничего не выводит, если добавить в контроллер echo $title, то выводит то что нужно

Comment: А расширение файлы шаблона у вас какое? Точно blade?

Comment: И вопрос в том как вы подключаете этот шаблон